# liminf and limsup in probability

Tags: probability-theory, self-learning

> Consider a sequence of random variable $(X_n)$. Prove the following inequality:
>   $$
> \mathbb P\left(\liminf\{X_n \leq x\}\right) \leq \liminf\mathbb P\left(\{X_n \leq x\}\right)\leq \limsup\mathbb P\left(\{X_n \leq x\}\right) \leq \mathbb P\left(\limsup\{X_n \leq x\}\right).
> $$

I can see that the **second** $\leq$ is simply the result for real sequence. However, I do not see how to get the **first** and the **last** one. It seems that the two are similar. Could anyone help me, please? Thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let $A_n = \{X_n \le x\}$. Then

$$\liminf A_n = \bigcup_{n \ge 1} \bigcap_{k\ge n} A_k$$

Since $\{\cap_{k\ge n} A_k\}_{n = 1}^\infty$ is a sequence which increases to $\liminf A_n$,

$$P(\liminf A_n) = \lim_{n\to \infty} P\left(\bigcap_{k \ge n} A_k\right)\tag{1}$$

by continuity of $P$ from below. Since $\cap_{k\ge n} A_k \subseteq A_n$ for all $n$, $P(\cap_{k\ge n} A_k) \le P(A_n)$ for all $n$. Hence

$$\liminf_{n\to \infty} P\left(\bigcap_{k \ge n} A_k\right) \le \liminf_{n\to \infty} P(A_n)\tag{2}$$

By $(1)$ and $(2)$,

$$P(\liminf_{n\to \infty} A_n) \le \liminf_{n\to \infty} P(A_n).$$

For the last equality, let $\Omega$ be the underlying sample space. Apply the lim inf inequality to the sequence $B_n = \Omega \setminus A_n$ to get $P(\limsup A_n) \ge \limsup P(A_n)$.

Comment: is there something wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 8):

This has nothing to do with random variables. Just let $A_n = \{X_n \leq x\}$

$$
\mathbb P\left(\liminf A_n\right) \leq \liminf\mathbb P\left(A_n\right)\leq \limsup\mathbb P\left(A_n\right) \leq \mathbb P\left(\limsup A_n\right).
$$

The inequalities are:

1. Fatou's Lemma
2. A real analysis proposition
3. Reverse Fatou's Lemma

Answer (score 3):

I would like to present a slightly general version here.

---

Let $(A_n)$ be a sequence of measurable sets. Then $$\mathbb P\left(\liminf  A_n \right) \leq \liminf\mathbb P\left( A_n \right) \leq \limsup\mathbb P\left( A_n \right) \leq \mathbb P\left(\limsup A_n \right).$$

---

The second inequality is clear from real analysis. Let's prove the first one. We have

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb P\left(\liminf  A_n \right) &= \mathbb P\left(\bigcup_{n} \bigcap_{k \ge n}  A_k \right) \\
&= \lim_{n} \mathbb P\left( \bigcap_{k \ge n}  A_k \right) \\
&\le \lim_n \inf_{k\ge n} \mathbb P\left( A_k \right) \text{ because }  \mathbb P\left( \bigcap_{k \ge n}  A_k \right) \le \mathbb P\left( A_t \right) \text{ for all } t\ge n\\
&= \liminf\mathbb P\left( A_n \right).
\end{aligned}
$$

Similarly, we have

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb P\left(\limsup  A_n \right) &= \mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{n} \bigcup_{k \ge n}  A_k \right) \\
&= \lim_{n} \mathbb P\left( \bigcup_{k \ge n}  A_k \right) \\
&\ge \lim_n \sup_{k\ge n} \mathbb P\left( A_k \right) \text{ because }  \mathbb P\left( \bigcup_{k \ge n}  A_k \right) \ge \mathbb P\left( A_t \right) \text{ for all } t\ge n\\
&= \limsup \mathbb P\left( A_n \right).
\end{aligned}
$$