# Continuity of Probability if $An\to A$ but neither increasing or decreasing

Tags: probability, probability-theory, continuity

Perhaps this is a silly question, but most books of probability talk about continuity of probability if either $A_n$ increases to $A$ or if $A_n$ decreases to $A$. My question is, if we just have that $A_n \to A$, does continuity of probability still holds? If so, why not just state that instead of separating the increasing and decreasing cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true. It is a trivial consequence of:

$$P(\liminf_{n\to\infty}A_n)\le\liminf_{n\to\infty}P(A_n)\le\limsup_{n\to\infty}P(A_n)\le P(\limsup_{n\to\infty}A_n)$$

You may find a proof of this inequality here: [liminf and limsup in probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1213536/liminf-and-limsup-in-probability/2764829)

Comment: Great, but do you have any idea why most books write the increasing and decreasing cases instead?

Comment: @DaviBarreira because most books you have read are probably tailored for less mathematically inclined audience for which the notion of union and intersection is fine but that of limits of infimums/supremums may be too much.

Comment: Not really. I mean, all measure theory books I’ve seen talk about  it like this.

Comment: Actually, I think I know why is that. Continuity from above (or below) plus finite additivity is enough for getting an equivalence with sigma additivity.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the general continuity property you stated; there are many equivalent ways of defining the same concept. However, you may notice that in order to apply your result to a sequence of sets $A_n$ one must first prove that $\liminf A_n=\limsup A_n=A$. In practice, it is almost always more natural/convenient to write $A$ as the limit of a monotone sequence, like in $\{f>0\}=\lim_n \{f>1/n\}$.

Comment: Also, if your measure is not finite there is a difference between continuity from below and continuity from above, in the sense that the continuity from above does not always hold, e.g. take the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ and $A_n=[n,\infty)\downarrow \emptyset$ but obiviously $\lambda(A_n)\not\to\lambda(\emptyset)$

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Momo proved that a probability measure is indeed continuous. Now, my other question was why not presenting such property instead of separating continuity from above and from below. I think I’ve figured why most books do this. The reason would be that continuity from above (or below) plus finite additivity is equivalent to $\sigma$-additivity. Hence why won would prove them instead of the stronger claim of continuity.